# AssertionError: 404 != 200 in django testing

Tags: python, django, testing

I have test code, but it displays error:
self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

```
class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.list_url = reverse('home')
        self.about_url = reverse('about', args=[1])

    def test_index(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.list_url)

        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'job_app/index.html')

    def test_about(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.about_url)

        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'job_app/about.html')
```

my url:

```
path('about/<int:pk>/', views.about.as_view(), name='about'),
```

view:

```
class about(DetailView):
    model = JobsModel
    template_name = 'job_app/about.html'
    context_object_name = 'job'
```

i dont know what to do

Comment: You did not create a `JobsModel` record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not create a `JobsModel` record. You should first create one:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        #               may require values 🖟🖟
        self.job = JobsModel.objects.create()
        self.list_url = reverse('home')
        self.about_url = reverse('about', args=[self.job.pk])

    def test_index(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.list_url)

        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'job_app/index.html')

    def test_about(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.about_url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'job_app/about.html')
```

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `AboutView`, instead of <s>`About`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `…Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`JobsModel`</s> to `Job`.

Comment: what values to add to self.job = JobsModel.objects.create(), if i have such model class JobsModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='my_data')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    work_position = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)

Comment: @Fit: all non-null values without a default, so `JobsModel.objects.create(company_name='foo', ...)`

Comment: NOT NULL constraint failed: job_app_jobsmodel.creator_id

Comment: @Fit: since `creator` is a non-nullable `ForeignKey`, you thus need to provide one for that as well. So you will first need to create a `User`, and then use that one for the `creator`...

Answer (score 1):

```
class TestViews(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    test_user = User.objects.create_user(username='test', password='password123')         #new!!!!!
    self.client = Client()
    self.job = JobsModel.objects.create(     #new!!!!!
        company_name = 'test',  
        description = 'test',
        salary = 1,
        work_position = 'test',
        phone_number = '1111111',
        email = 'test@gmail.com',
        creator = User.objects.get(username='test'),   #new!!!!!!
        
    )
    self.list_url = reverse('home')
    self.about_url = reverse('about', args=[self.job.pk])

def test_index(self):
    response = self.client.get(self.list_url)

    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'job_app/index.html')

def test_about(self):
    response = self.client.get(self.about_url)

    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'job_app/about.html')
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**